# Passing authorization to cloudinary in react

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I'm making the front of an app in react and i need to upload images to cloudinary passing the key and secret. I tried this:

```
function handleFiles(files) {
    const url = CLOUDINARY_URL
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file",files[0])
    formData.append('upload_preset',IMAGE_FOLDER)
    fetch(url,{
      method: "POST",
      //headers: {
      //  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + CLOUDINARY_KEY + ":" + CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
      //},
      body: formData
    }).then(response => {console.log("resp ",response); return response.text()})
    .then(data => console.log("data ", data))
}
```

This code works fine with a cloud name that doesn't need authorization but when i uncomment the header part give me the next error
*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at CLOUDINARY_URL. (Reason: header ‘authorization’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)*

How can i achieve this? Or is there other way to upload images from react?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary Upload API does not use Basic Authorization method to signed your upload. However it can be uploaded using Signed Upload preset that signed with your backend or unsigned upload preset. I suggest to check their [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#direct_uploading_from_the_browser) to learn the difference.

The easiest to upload via web, although it's not specific to React, is to use Cloudinary's [Upload Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget). This is JavaScript based solution that you can integrate with your React App

On a last note, just keep in mind that your API credential, specifically API Secret should be treated as if it's your password. Since React is a client-side application, you should not put your API secret there.

Comment: The problem is that i need to use the the secret because it is not implemented in the backend so i have to use like a node js app but when i use `const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2` give me the next error **error - ./node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:1:0**
**Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'**.